# I keep getting thrown 'Tuple index out of range' error

Tags: python, data-science

As a project I'm currently writing a matchmaking system. And I am currently on the actual matchmaking portion of the code now. However, I keep on getting thrown the 'tuple index out of range' error. I have looked over this so many times and I just cant seem to figure out whats wrong. All my tuples have a length greater than 2, but when I try and access index value 1 on line 117, It throws the error

```
UsersID = []
UsersAGE = []
UsersMUSIC = []
UsersGENDER = []
UsersLFG = []
UsersMAINT = []
#User ID 
x = input('Enter lowest users I.D. number: ')
y = input('Enter highest users I.D. number: ')
for num in range(int(x),int(y)+1):
    UsersID.append((num))
print(UsersID)
#User ID

#User AGE
Q = 0 + int(x)
while Q <= int(y):
    Q += 1
    q = input('Enter age: ')
    UsersAGE.append(int(q))
print(UsersAGE)
#User AGE

#UserGENDER
W = 0 + int(x)
while W <= int(y):
    W += 1
    w = input('Enter gender: ')
    UsersGENDER.append(w)
print(UsersGENDER)
#UserGENDER

#UsersLFG
E = 0 + int(x)
while E <= int(y):
    E += 1
    e = input('Enter LFG: ')
    if e == "Indifferent/Doesn't matter":
        UsersLFG.append('Female, Male, Non-binary, Agender, Intersex, Two-Spirt')
    if e != "Indifferent/Doesn't matter":
        UsersLFG.append(e)
print(UsersLFG)
#UsersLFG

#UsersMUSIC
R = 0 + int(x)
while R <= int(y):
    R += 1
    r = input('Enter Music type: ')
    UsersMUSIC.append(r)
print(UsersMUSIC)
#UsersMUSIC

#UsersMA-INT
T = 0 + int(x)
while T <= int(y):
    T += 1
    t = input('Enter Main interests: ')
    UsersMAINT.append(t)
print(UsersMAINT)
#UsersMA-INT

print('Loading........')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
print('---------------')
Users = []
ALA = 0
while ALA <= (int(y)-int(x)):
    BLB = (UsersID[ALA],UsersAGE[ALA],UsersGENDER[ALA],UsersLFG[ALA],UsersMUSIC[ALA],UsersMAINT[ALA])
    Users.extend([BLB])
    ALA += 1
print(Users)

A13 = []
A14 = []
A15 = []
A16 = []
A17 = []
for user in Users:
    if user[1] == 13:A13.append(user)
    if user[1] == 14:A14.append(user)
    if user[1] == 15:A15.append(user)
    if user[1] == 16:A16.append(user)
    if user[1] == 17:A17.append(user)
SORTEDUsers = A13 + A14 + A15 + A16 + A17



print('------')
print(A13)
print('------')
print(A14)
print('------')
print(A15)
print('------')
print(A16)
print('------')
print(A17)
print('------')

print(SORTEDUsers)

for person in A13:
    SORTEDUsers.remove(person)
    A13.remove(person)
    for persons in SORTEDUsers:
        if person[1] == (persons[1] + 1) or person[1] == (persons[1]) and (persons[2] in person[3]) and person[6] in persons[6]: 
            print(person[0],persons[0])
            SORTEDUsers.remove(persons)
            if persons in A13: A13.remove(persons)
            if persons in A14: A14.remove(persons)
            break
```

Does anyone know why I am getting thrown this error? And if so, how do I fix it? The error is getting thrown at line 117

Comment: Please include full stack trace.

Comment: So like the line the error is getting thrown at? If so, it's line 117

Comment: right after ```for persons in SORTEDUsers:```, what is the content of ```person``` and ```persons```?

Comment: The content is their ID, Age, Gender, Gender they are looking for, Music they like, and main interests

Comment: But I'm so confused because I am trying to access index value 1 of persons and person and it has 6 values inside of it. But it's giving that error.

Comment: python uses a -zero index.  Meaning person[1] is actually the 2nd person.

Comment: I know that. Persons and person are both tuples. And I'm trying to access the index value 1 of both of those tuples. But I'm getting that error.

Comment: what's the length of both ```person``` and ```persons```?

Comment: the length is 6, they contain 6 variables, ID, Age, Gender, Gender they are looking for, Music they like, and main interests

Comment: then ```persons[6]``` is invalid.   ```persons[5]``` is what you want for the last item. ditto with ```person```

Comment: But the length of it is 6, and when I try to access persons[1], it gives me the error when it shouldn't

Comment: Oh my God, I am so sorry, it was really late and I was super stressed out. I am a complete idiot, I was completely overlooking the other conditionals. Thanks for the help.